# How to calculate Pi decimals from a given offset?

Tags: command-line, syntax

I am using http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/math/pi to calculate Pi decimals.

Let's say I want only decimals from the 3rd decimal to the 5th decimal.
`man pi` says it is possible to enter an interval but does not say how:

> - SYNOPSIS
>     pi [digits]
> - DESCRIPTION
>     The pi command prints 100 decimal digits of Archimedes' constant pi or a number of digits specified by an integer parameter on the command line.

PROBLEM: I can't seem to guess what the syntax is:

```
$ pi 3-5
3.14         <-- Not what I want
$ pi 3,5
3.14
$ pi 3:5
3.14
```

What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pi` wants you to specify how many digits of the value to compute. Each of your attempts above has [some digits][a non-digit][who cares], and the [digits], is all cases, is "3". Try  `pi 10 | cut -c5-7`, or, since **pi** is a constant, why not use `echo "159"`?

Comment: Ah so actually I can't calculate from a given offset... I am actually interested in the digits from 13 trillion to 13.1 trillion.

Comment: I hope there is another tool: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/13982/tool-to-calculate-pi-3-14-from-a-given-digit-on-linux